# I am trying to post a JSON object to a ASP.NET MVC Controller but getting empty JSON

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, post, model-view-controller

Here is the Javascript code

```js
$("#JSONPost").click(function (e) {
    var jsonData = { name: "ramesh", mobile: "9xxxxxxxxx" };
    $.post(
        "/Trace/JSONPostMethod",
        jsonData,
        function (data, status) {
            alert(status);
        });
    });
});
```

```
public ActionResult JSONPostMethod(object data)
{

}
```

data is coming as `{}` instead of the `{ name: "ramesh", mobile: "9xxxxxxxxx" }`

Any idea how to get this JSON? I don't want to create a model class to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Inside the controller method do this,

```
var resolveRequest = HttpContext.Request;
resolveRequest.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
string jsonString = new StreamReader(resolveRequest.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your Json code and write something which is not confusing as below:

```js
$("#JSONPost").click(function (e) {
    var jsonData= {};
    jsonData.Name = "Ramesh";
    jsonData.Mobile = "9xxxxxxxxx";
    
    $.ajax(
        url: "/Trace/JSONPostMethod",
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data, status) {
            alert(status);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Correction in your Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult JSONPostMethod(object data)
{
   // your logic here
   return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No change in output,

Comment: [HttpPost]
public ActionResult JSONPostMethod(object data)
{
      string jsonstr = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
}

Comment: jsonStr is coming as "{}"

Comment: IN the $.ajax method, I forgot to mention the success property. I have edited my answer. Have a look. Also, the return type of your Controller should be JsonResult

Comment: If you are passing Json into a controller, it should be of Json type. I have updated my answer I am sure you will get it in your controller variable.

Comment: still getting "{}" as json string

Comment: @RameshViswanathan can you write your code in fiddle and show me?

Comment: I don't know about fiddle. Can you guide me?

Comment: @RameshViswanathan this is the link for .Net fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/E7ak0N. To save your work, you need to login. Write your code into this fiddle, save it. But since you've found the answer no need to send me.